# javascript extra large negative exponent to decimal conversion

Tags: javascript, math, immutable.js, exponential, tofixed

How would I get this negative large exponential number 6.849391775995509e-276 to 6.84 in javascript?

I'm getting back negative exponential numbers from an api which I would like to use a shortened version, to 2 decimal points, in my ui. If it matters, im using the number in a d3 chart rendering in react.

I have been trying some different techniques from the javascript doc sites but can not seem to get it to. Is using a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) an option? Any help would be greatly appreciated. All of the attempts in the code snippet which use the exponent notation return `0.00`.

```js
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}
console.log(financial(6.849391775995509e-276));
const num = 6.849391775995509e-276
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
const num2 = 6.84939;
console.log(num2.toFixed(2));

console.log(financial('6.849391775995509e-276'));
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. None of these numbers are negative.

Comment: @ninesalt negative exponent (i.e., after the `e`), not negative number.

Comment: @ninesalt 6.849391775995509e-276 as opposed to 1.23e+5 in docs example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Anyway, how would Immutable.js help you here? It has nothing to do with number manipulation.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i saw some code that achieved using to fixed and got 6.84  using toFixed(2) so I though maybe this might be built in to that library. Couldnt find it though.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Jonas' answer, however you want to wrap it in `parseFloat()` to get an actual number rather than a string.

```js
const num = 6.849391775995509e-276
var newNum = parseFloat(num.toString().substr(0,4)) 
console.log(newNum)
```

Comment: "to get an actual number rather than a string" That's the reason for the `+` at the beginning of Jonas' answer.

Comment: @ninesalt who is Jonas?

Comment: @idkjs the author of the other answer, Jonas W.

Comment: looks like maybe `var newNum = parseFloat(num.toString().substr(0,4))` to get the second digit after the decimal. (0.3) gets you 6.8. http://jsbin.com/tobulom/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

```
 +num.toString().substr(0,3)
```

Just convert it to a string and take the first digits.